# How do I make an interactive command line interface?

Tags: c++, shell, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a tool to compare my files but I found it difficult to interactive with. I want to support 2 operations: 1) load my files into memory 2) compare the files already loaded.

The idea is like below

```
while (true) {
    getline(&line, &linesize, stdin);
    if (strlen(line) < 2) continue;
    token = strtok(line, DELIM);
    if (!strcmp(token,"load")) {
        puts("you want to load something");
    } else if (!strcmp(token, "compare")) {
        puts("you want to compare something");
    } else if (!strcmp(token, "exit")) {
        puts("exiting...");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        puts("Cannot parse, try again");
    }
}
```

In terminal, if I want to compare some `MyVeryLongFileNameFile.foo` and  `AnotherVeryLongFileNameFile.bar`, I can just type `diff My\tab Ano\tab \enter` and it will auto completes the filenames for me.

I would like to also have these kind of features in my program, like using tab to autocomplete, using up/down to choose from previous commands, etc. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [ncurses.h library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS) help you accomplish this.

Comment: @interputed I just discovered this discussion. I'd like to improve my under-construction-GUI in which a text field that user can use to type will act like a terminal, and I find your answer. Many thanks. May I ask if ncurses library allow me also to send the text line the user wrote to the "real" terminal (Ubuntu 14.04) and have the string executed there?

Comment: To send a string to the Ubuntu terminal would require a system call. If you include the header `#include <cstdlib>`, then you can use `system()` which takes a string that it runs in the terminal.